# How to prevent an app from sharing its data with Google?

Tags: backup, sms, privacy, mms, google-backup

The changelog of a popular SMS/MMS app, Textra, states:

> Textra is now backed up **automatically** *[emphasis added]* using the built-in Google Backup service. Makes it so easy to swap devices or uninstall / reinstall without losing your settings and any customization! Supported from Android 6.

*Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20210519012025/https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.textra*

What does this really mean?  In Android 7.0 is there a way to disable a single app from sharing private/personal data with Google?  If not, how about all apps?

The app itself does not appear to have any options regarding this unwanted functionality.

Comment: You can completely disable GDrive Backup in Android settings then it doesn't matter if the apps allow cloud backup.

Comment: That's what I'd recommend as well: disable it (you have close to no control about it anyway and never know what's backed up and will restore and what not), and take care for backups yourself. Note that LineageOS started adopting [Seedvault](https://github.com/seedvault-app/seedvault) as replacement for that G-Backup; with Seedvault you not only can define where your backups end up (local SD card, Nextcloud etc) but also see what is backed up, what not, and control it. So if such a custom ROM is an option… ;)

Comment: look into [TrackerControl](https://trackercontrol.org/) - you can get it from [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/)

Answer (score 5):

See [Data backup overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup). Since changelog is talking of Android 6 compatibility, it is referring to *Android auto backup* (see table).

> Enabled by default. Apps can opt out by disabling backups.

Contextually, it implies Textra had opted out of back up earlier and now has it enabled.

There is *no option* for the user to choose which apps can be backed up or not. Either they backup or not (search settings for backup to see the toggle switch). If backup is enabled, apps that are enabled for backup are backed up.

Developers can choose to exclude some parts of app data even if backup is enabled. Backup data size is limited to 25 MB and doesn't count for your drive storage usage. Users have no control on *what* is backed up, so if you don't trust Google (good idea) look for custom ROM options as suggested by [Izzy in comments](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/237200/how-to-prevent-an-app-from-sharing-its-data-with-google/237205#comment314404_237200) or turn  off backup in settings.

Comment: Thanks.  I do my best to send as little as possible to Google.  I regularly go through Google's settings, and turn everything off.  Then a month later, I'll go through the settings again, only to see they created a new setting with a default of "on". I want to ensure I have this particular setting off.  Exactly where is this setting? [comment moderated by a mod]

Comment: I don't have a device running Android 7 to tell you the location. Sorry, but you can search in Google accounts maybe or ask another question with this linked as background