# If I have two phones, and I use the same email address for google play store, will it back them up individually?

Tags: google-play-store, backup

If I have two phones, and I use the same email address for google play store, will it back them up individually?

For example, would each phone have its own apps that are backed up?

Or would they end up with the same apps installed?

Comment: And what exactly is backed up with that "backup to google drive" option that comes up when opening google play store on a phone where it's not logged into google play?

And when google play store asks you to login , is that generic or just google play?

Comment: See [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/237205/131553) for related matter //each phone would be individually backed up

Comment: You can choose from which device you want to backup https://android.stackexchange.com/a/191324/131553